# Hot reload failing to update file changes

Tags: css, workflow

I have been trying to get my wordpress project to use hot reload, but when changes are made to my files, nothing is changed/updated.

I initially had it executing like this from my functions.php file:

```
function workshop_01_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script('workshop_01-js', 'http://localhost:3000/bundled.js', NULL, '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'workshop_01_theme');
```

Which has been working perfectly and output in F12 console:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...               log.js:24
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.                     index.js:48 
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.                             index.js:52
```

However, when I wish to use hot reload whereby I create a manifest.json file that will contain a map of source filenames to the corresponding build output files like this:

```
function workshop_01_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script('workshop_01-js', get_theme_file_uri('/bundled-assets/scripts.bedc8565a6cb22e37037.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('worskshop_01-style', get_theme_file_uri('/bundled-assets/styles.bedc8565a6cb22e37037.css'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'workshop_01_theme');
```

When I refresh the browser after running my script: npm run dev, then make changes to any of my pages or css, nothing is automatically reloaded in the browser unless I manually hit the refresh button, and nothing is being outputted in the F12 console, nada!

I dont get any errors/warnings regarding this issue in the command line, so I dont know how to rectify it.

Here are my package.json, webpack.config.js, manifest.json, scripts.js, and my file structure:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "workshop_01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all -p devFast buildWatch",
    "devFast": "webpack serve",
    "buildWatch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.6",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-color-function": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-hexrgba": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "postcss-mixins": "^8.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
/*
  SUPER IMPORTANT: This config assumes your theme folder is named
  exactly 'fictional-university-theme' and that you have a folder
  inside it named 'bundled-assets' - If you'd like to adapt this
  config to work with your own custom folder structure and names
  be sure to adjust the publicPath value on line #116. You do NOT
  need to update any of the other publicPath settings in this file,
  only the one on line #116.
*/

const currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin")
const fse = require("fs-extra")

const postCSSPlugins = [require("postcss-import"), require("postcss-mixins"), require("postcss-simple-vars"), require("postcss-nested"), require("postcss-hexrgba"), require("postcss-color-function"), require("autoprefixer")]

class RunAfterCompile {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("Update functions.php", function () {
      // update functions php here
      const manifest = fse.readJsonSync("./bundled-assets/manifest.json")

      fse.readFile("./functions.php", "utf8", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }

        const scriptsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/scripts.+?'", "g")
        const vendorsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/vendors.+?'", "g")
        const cssRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/styles.+?'", "g")

        let result = data.replace(scriptsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.js"]}'`).replace(vendorsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["vendors~scripts.js"]}'`).replace(cssRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.css"]}'`)

        fse.writeFile("./functions.php", result, "utf8", function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err)
        })
      })
    })
  }
}

let cssConfig = {
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ["css-loader?url=false", { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: postCSSPlugins } }]
}

let config = {
  entry: {
    scripts: "./js/scripts.js"
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      cssConfig,
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "12" } }]]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

if (currentTask == "devFast") {
  config.devtool = "source-map"
  cssConfig.use.unshift("style-loader")
  config.output = {
    filename: "bundled.js",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/"
  }
  config.devServer = {
    before: function (app, server) {
      /*
        If you want the browser to also perform a traditional refresh
        after a save to a JS file you can modify the line directly
        below this comment to look like this instead. I'm using this approach
        instead of just disabling Hot Module Replacement beacuse this way our
        CSS updates can still happen immediately without a page refresh.
        If you're using a slower computer and the new bundle is not ready
        by the time this is reloading the browser you can always just set the 
        "hot" property a few lines below this to false instead of true. That
        will work on all computers and the only trade off is the browser will
        perform a traditional refresh even for CSS changes as well.
        */

      // server._watch(["./**/*.php", "./**/*.js"])
      server._watch(["./**/*.php", "!./functions.php"])
    },
    public: "http://localhost:3000",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    disableHostCheck: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
    contentBasePublicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
  config.mode = "development"
}

if (currentTask == "build" || currentTask == "buildWatch") {
  cssConfig.use.unshift(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader)
  postCSSPlugins.push(require("cssnano"))
  config.output = {
    publicPath: "/wp-content/themes/workshop_01/bundled-assets/",
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bundled-assets")
  }
  config.mode = "production"
  config.optimization = {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" }
  }
  config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "styles.[chunkhash].css" }), new ManifestPlugin({ publicPath: "" }), new RunAfterCompile())
}

module.exports = config
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "scripts.css": "styles.bedc8565a6cb22e37037.css",
  "scripts.js": "scripts.bedc8565a6cb22e37037.js"
}
```

scripts.js

```
import "../css/style.css"

// Allow new JS and CSS to load in browser without a traditional page refresh
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

files structure

[image]

I don't know whether I need another plugin or need to replace a plugin or to modify the webpack.config.js file.

When I check the F12 console for changes, its outputs nothing either...

I have researched similar issues, but nothing has helped me clarify the issue I'm having.

Comment: Have you checked the page source to ensure that your enqueued script and style have actually loaded?

Comment: I have said I checked f12 console in the browser, but nothing is being reloaded regarding the hot reload. Page source shows my css file is there, so my page displays as it should. The script.js only imports the css file and checks if (module.hot) {module.hot.accept()}

Comment: It must have something to do with the webpack.config file, but I dont know what it is... :/

Comment: It looks like the hot reload version is no longer being loaded, as you removed it and put new enqueues in that load built assets directly instead of using the hot reload server. You will need to consult the documentation for your hot reloading solution to discover the correct URL to enqueue as the problem is not with WordPress and WordPress knowledge will not be helpful here